# how we can optimise grafana dashboards?

Tags: optimization, prometheus, grafana, dashboard

How we can optimize the grafana dashboards? what are steps we can do to optimize the dashboards? Does adding rows help in optimising the dashboard?

Comment: Can you specify why you want to optimize the dashboards and what you want to optimize for?

Comment: inorder to load the data quickly without any delay and to avoid server load.

Comment: what time line db are you using? @Elzin?